# Basic authenticiation in $http Get request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, request-headers

I am trying to access a REST API service with basic authenticiation.

This works perfectly as a curl request:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic eW**********0NQ==" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.domain.com/api/users/email/first.last@domain.com"
```

In angular, I tried this and it does not seem to work as I get a `501` error...

```
var _url = "https://api.domain.com/api/users/email/first.last@domain.com";
var _authdata = Base64.encode('MyUsername' + ':' + 'MyPassword');
var _headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Basic eWd***********0NQ==',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'               
};

$http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: _url,
     headers: _headers
}).then(function(request) {
     console.log('request');
});
```

I am trying to understand why this isn't working out properly. CORS are not the problem...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: So, What's the server response? `401`, `403`, any other?

Comment: You're sending a post instead of a get. You also don't use _authdata.

Comment: Try `method: 'GET'` 501 comes when something is not implemented and you are trying to do that

Comment: Oh yes sorry, wrong copy&paste. But GET it is and the answer is 501.

Answer (score 0):

**Base64.encode is not understandable by angular-js either you can use javascript "btao" and "atob" or you can include the base64 through npm**

Maybe the following code snippet will help you.

```
var _url = "https://api.domain.com/api/users/email/first.last@domain.com";
  var _authdata = btoa('MyUsername' + ':' + 'MyPassword');
  var _headers = {
     'Authorization': 'Basic' + _authdata,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'               
  };

  $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: _url,
       json: true,
       headers: _headers
  }).then(function(request) {
       console.log('request');
  });
```

or you can include the Angular-base64 dependency using npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-base64